# Salesforce Branding for Mobile Metadata

Tags: mobile, document, asset, theme-branding, content-assets

Is it possible to retrieve metadata for settings of Salesforce Branding for Mobile application?

I have found only metadata for logo stored in documents/Salesforce_Branding_Resources but it is nowhere referenced. Also I could not have found my Brand and Loading Page color assignments.
For Desktop branding from Themes and Branding setup option, it is stored correctly in brandingSets and contentassets metadata.

Thanks!